# How to determine if browser supports properties on event object?

Tags: javascript, custom-event

Some touch-enabled browsers (such as Mobile Safari) have a `scale` and `rotation` property available on their `event` object for events such as `touchmove`.

I can detect support for the `scale` property like so...

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    var supportsScaleProperty = !!event.scale;
});
```

However, is there a way to detect it without having to bind a listener and then look for the property in the callback?

For example, if this worked?

```
var supportsScaleProperty = !!(new CustomEvent("TouchEvents")).scale;
```

I tried looking at [`createEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent), but it's deprecated. I looked at `new CustomEvent()`, but wasn't sure which string to use for touch events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be possible. [TJ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397852/31671) doesn't tell me if the properties exist (they're never present, even on devices which support them).

So, it looks like I'm stuck with...

```
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
    if (event.scale) {
         // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use an [`Event` constructor](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#event):

```
if ('scale' in new Event("touchmove")) {
    // It has it
}
```

Comment: ...although sadly, your mileage may vary. On Chrome, at least, `new Event("mousemove")` doens't have `pageX`, but a real `mousemove` event does: http://jsbin.com/ijigov/1 (http://jsbin.com/ijigov/1/edit).

Comment: And it doesn't have it even if you dispatch the event: http://jsbin.com/ijigov/2 (http://jsbin.com/ijigov/2/edit). So it'll depend in your target browser whether it fills in `scale` and `rotation` or expects your code creating the event to.

Comment: Thanks! I can't check now, but will later tonight. :)

Comment: You're right, on Mobile Safari it doesn't have either the `scale` or `rotation` properties. Bummer.

Comment: According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events), IE doesn't support the `new Event()` constructor.

Comment: @10basetom: MDN is *community-edited*, not official information from Mozilla. IE11 definitely has the event constructor. IE8 probably doesn't. :-) [Alex Rauschmeyer says IE10 doesn't have it, though](http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html). I trust him.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I think IE11 and above supports it then since on my IE10 `typeof Event` returns 'object' instead of 'function'.