# If browser supports event.code

Tags: javascript, events, browser, keyboard-events

I need to understand if browser supports event.code before event happens, I couldn't find anything interesting about it, so maybe someone can help me with it

Comment: I've had trouble before with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17397814/31671) FWIW.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877393/detecting-support-for-a-given-javascript-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found solution for it, window.KeyboardEvent.prototype.code returns undefined if browser don't supports event.code and if it supports it returns error.